Is there a legal sense/use of νομίζω?
Seems weird to be asking a question about ancient Greek in a Latin site, but it is what it is.
This question is very specific, having to do with the use of νομίζω (nomizo) in the passive with the genitive:  when used of the relationship between two people, does it ever indicate that as the first person being legal heir of the second person?

By the very basic two meaning, act according to the rules, believe to be true, a passive with genitive can mean only some  belived identity; 'Ηρακλης νομιζεται του Διος κατα νομου'  evaluates to 'Herakles is thought to be Zeus by law'

Is there a specific text or something else that motivated your question? I would guess that the issue here might just be that a name in the genitive means "son of X," which is of course an heir, nothing to do with νομίζω

FWIW, the LSJ entry doesn't mention such a usage.
Literally, Φαίδων Σωκράτους νομίζεται would mean "Phaedo is considered (to be) of Socrates", which probably would not imply a status as heir -- if anything, it seems like it might imply that Ph. is S.'s adopted son (though I don't have an example of that usage either).
